# firebird - after insert or update trigger

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, triggers, firebird

I have a calculation in my DB need to update "field1" for "table1" after the update trigger.

The problem that updating that field will cause the after update trigger to fire and execute a lengthy procedure and display errors.

please advise how to update the "field1" after the "After update" trigger has been executed and without making the "after update" trigger to execute again.

I know that I can not use NEW with After trigger.

Thanks

Comment: how about using the BEFORE UPDATE trigger?

Comment: "I know that I can not use NEW with After trigger."  Why? NEW and OLD meta variables are available for both BEFORE and AFTER UPDATE triggers.

Comment: @AndreiK. The OP probably means that one can't  **write** into `NEW` context variable in AFTER trigger. Reading them of course is OK...

Comment: @ain Exactly............

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can use a custom locking mechanism based on context variables which prevent from repeating invocation of AFTER UPDATE trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER au FOR table
  AFTER UPDATE
  POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
  IF RDB$GET_CONTEXT('USER_TRANSACTION', 'MY_LOCK') IS NULL THEN
  BEGIN
    RDB$SET_CONTEXT('USER_TRANSACTION', 'MY_LOCK', 1);

    ...
    Do your update operations here
    ...

    RDB$SET_CONTEXT('USER_TRANSACTION', 'MY_LOCK', NULL);
  END

  WHEN ANY DO
  BEGIN
    RDB$SET_CONTEXT('USER_TRANSACTION', 'MY_LOCK', NULL);
    EXCEPTION;
  END
END
```

Comment: thats cool same like using global variable....but instead of using exception I will probably will use exit......thanks alot I will check the solution soon.

Comment: WHEN ANY section here is for insurance that lock will expire if something gets wrong. EXCEPTION here is for RETHROWING exception if any.

Comment: 1) "can I use "updating" for..." -- in AFTER or BEFORE UPDATE triggers UPDATING metavariable will always result in TRUE. 2) "better to use EXIT or suspend" -- this is trigger, not stored proc. SUSPEND is not applicable for triggers. As for stored procs SUSPEND is for returning row in SELECTABLE procedures.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is to switch to the `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, as pointed out by J Cooper... however, if there is some reason you absolutely have to use `AFTER UPDATE` then you have to set up a flag which tells that the field needs to be recalculated and check it in your trigger. One way to do it would be to set the field to `NULL` in `BEFORE` trigger and then check against NULL in `AFTER` trigger, ie

```
CREATE TRIGGER bu_trigger BEFORE UPDATE
BEGIN
  -- mark field for recalculation if needed
  IF(update invalidates the field1 value)THEN
     NEW.field1 = NULL;
END

CREATE TRIGGER au_trigger AFTER UPDATE
BEGIN
  -- only update if the field is NULL
  IF(NEW.field1 IS NULL)THEN
     UPDATE table1 SET field1 = ...;
END
```

But using this technique you probably have to use lot of `IF(OLD.field IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.field)THEN` checks in triggers to avoid unnessesary updates in your triggers.

Answer (score 0):

simple solution...

fire the update only **if the NEW.FIELD1 value is really new**, like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER au FOR table1
  AFTER UPDATE
  POSITION 0
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE TMP AS NUMBER(15,5); -- SAME DATATYPE OF FIELD1
BEGIN
  -- MAKE YOUR CALCULATION
  TMP=CALCULATEDVALUE;
  -- UPDATE THE ROW ONLY IF THE VALUES IS CHANGED
  IF (TMP<>NEW.FIELD1) UPDATE TABLE1 SET FIELD1=:TMP WHERE KEY=NEW.KEY; -- PAY ATTENTION IF TMP OR NEW.FIELD1 CAN BE NULL. IN THIS CASE USE COALESCE OR A DIFFERENCE COMPARISON
END
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution: Use `BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER` instead of `AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER`

```
CREATE TRIGGER some_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ... etc
```